# WCF - Disable browser authentication for client app

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have created a WCF OData Service using .NET4.5 with C#. In the application, there is a form  Basic authentication implemented that uses ASP.NET Identity which works well.

Following is my code in the service app, where I intercept the authorization header and authenticate the request.

```
 protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
         bool isAuthenticated = CustomBasicAuth.Authenticate(HttpContext.Current);
         if (!isAuthenticated)
         {
             args.OperationContext.ResponseHeaders.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
             HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
             throw new DataServiceException(401, "Invalid login or password");
         }

        base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
    }
```

So whenever I access the service app in browser, it would prompt for the browser login. This is great for testing purpose.

[image: Browser Login Form]

Then I have a web based client which calls the service. On invalid login, it returns the 401 error, which is expected and I can handle it. But it also prompts the browser login form. How can I suppress this form in client app. (Disabling browser properties is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

You can deny access to the service / location for un-authenticated users, through **web.config**:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Path/To/Folder/YourService.svc">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
...
</configuration>
```

The same pattern can be applied to any aspx page, asmx classic web service, etc.

Comment: My authorization is working well. I just need to suppress the browser login form.